# How do you say "take away from someone else"?

Tags: word-choice

I am not a native speaker of English. I want to know if there is a verb that means "take away something from other people".

For example: If you say *I take it away* do you understand that (in most cases) you take something away from other people? Removing it from the other person?

Is there a better verb than *take away*?

In Spanish the word is *quitar*. In most cases it means "from other".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might be looking for either "seize" or "confiscate"

from Oxford Dictionary of English:

> **Confiscate**
> *Verb* [with object] take or seize (someone's property) with authority:
> "the guards confiscated his camera"
>
> **Seize**
> *Verb* [with object] take forcible possession of:
> "army rebels seized an air base"